# build tree by references with parents and id

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, reference

Although there are many solution i came across, mostely they are based on recursion. I would appreciate if someone can explain and convert this function from recursion to php references.

```
// build tree for Tree users
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ((string)$element['parent_id']  === (string)$parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['child'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
            // depthCommissionCalc($branch);  
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

i did tried myself but couldn't go into inner child depth because i am really knew to php references concept. there are many close solution to build tree by php references but all of them retain ID or parent Id as array index. which is not what i desire. for example this

```
function create($data){
    foreach($data as &$v){
        // Get childs
        if(isset($tree[$v['id']])) $v['child'] =& $tree[$v['id']];

        // push node into parent
        $tree[$v['parent_id']][$v['id']] =& $v;             

        // push child into node
        $tree[$v['id']]   =& $v['child'];
    }
    // return Tree
    return $tree[0];
}
```

and example array would be

```
$test = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "a", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "b", 'parent_id' => 1),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "c", 'parent_id' => 1),
        array('id' => 8, 'name' => "d", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => "e", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 5, 'name' => "f", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 6, 'name' => "i", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 7, 'name' => "j", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 11, 'name' => "k", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 9, 'name' => "l", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 10, 'name' => "m", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 12, 'name' => "n", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 13, 'name' => "o", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 14, 'name' => "p", 'parent_id' => 10),
        array('id' => 15, 'name' => "q", 'parent_id' => 10),
        array('id' => 16, 'name' => "r", 'parent_id' => 15),
        array('id' => 17, 'name' => "s", 'parent_id' => 16),
        array('id' => 18, 'name' => "t", 'parent_id' => 17),
)
```

would appreciate if someone can look into it and help converting the same function by using references instead of recursion and explain as well. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two-pass implementation can be found in [DbSimple](https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/DbSimple/blob/27ae5a92686a69374cdf870e457b7d8cb3ef416f/lib/DbSimple/Generic.php#L986). Every unknown `parent_id` become new root, child elements will be placed into `childNodes`:

```php
$test = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => "a", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => "b", 'parent_id' => 1),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => "c", 'parent_id' => 1),
        array('id' => 8, 'name' => "d", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => "e", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 5, 'name' => "f", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 6, 'name' => "i", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 7, 'name' => "j", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 11, 'name' => "k", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 9, 'name' => "l", 'parent_id' => 0),
        array('id' => 10, 'name' => "m", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 12, 'name' => "n", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 13, 'name' => "o", 'parent_id' => 7),
        array('id' => 14, 'name' => "p", 'parent_id' => 10),
        array('id' => 15, 'name' => "q", 'parent_id' => 10),
        array('id' => 16, 'name' => "r", 'parent_id' => 15),
        array('id' => 17, 'name' => "s", 'parent_id' => 16),
        array('id' => 18, 'name' => "t", 'parent_id' => 17),
);


$forest = _transformResultToForest($test, 'id', 'parent_id');
print_r($forest);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => a
            [childNodes] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => b
                            [childNodes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => c
                            [childNodes] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => d
            [childNodes] => Array
                (
                )

        )
...
```

Comment: hi thanks you for the effort, i will check and test it asap! cheers

Comment: sorry to not get back im still busy but i think i will give you +1 for great finding although my question asked conversation and explanation of the recursion function