# get hierarchy of users by parent

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, out-of-memory

I am trying to get all child and grand child and their child in PHP

**code**

```
$usrtoGet = 1;
array_push($juniors, $usrtoGet);

$sql = $db->Query("select usr_id from crm_users where usr_reporting_head=?", array($usrtoGet));
$result=$db->FetchAllArray($sql);

foreach ($result as $res) {
    $juniors[] = $res['usr_id'];
    getChildUsers($res['usr_id']);
}

function getChildUsers($res){
    global $db;
    global $juniors;

    $sql = $db->Query("select usr_id from crm_users where usr_reporting_head=?", array($res));
        $result=$db->FetchAllArray($sql);
        foreach($result as $two){
            array_push($juniors, $two['usr_id']);
            getChildUsers($two['usr_id']);
        }
    }
```

At first I got the desired result correctly later I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 468975616) (tried to allocate 44 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\adodb\drivers\adodb-mysql.inc.php on line 706

I have tried adjusting

```
ini_set('memory_limit','2G');
```

but no use.

If i comment out the line `getChildUsers($two['usr_id']);` on function getChildUsers it was working because of not searching for grandchilds is there any way to get this desired solution?

Comment: Take a look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48880520/8547799), DbSimple implementation does not use recursion at all and consumes less memory. And avoid usage of `global` if you able to, it makes your code fragile and hard to understand.